# how to post a pic I took to someone's wall on fb?

Tags: htc-desire, facebook

1. I took a pic on my HTC Desire 2.1
2. I want to post it to somebody's else wall on facebook so facebook stores the picture?
3. any easy way how to do this?

I guess I can find the pic on my mobile and then upload it using full site facebook interface. It's bit too complicated, isn't it.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this via the Facebook app as it currently exists. Even the mobile interface (m.facebook.com) doesn't offer image upload. You'll need to do it via the full site.

Comment: I thought so but I hoped that there would be a nice solution to that. Could you create an answer from that? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Upload it to a generic image hosting site. Copy the url and put it in a comment on 'someone's' wall.

Comment: good suggestion but I want fb only solution ...

Comment: How about uploading it to your own profile, then sharing that link on the other person's page? At the bottom, below a picture you've posted you should see "Share this photo with anyone by sending them this public link:" followed by a url.